# Run stored procedure when database comes online

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and higher, I'm wondering if it's possible for a stored procedure to auto-execute when a database comes online? I've found [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1574/automatically-running-stored-procedures-at-sql-server-startup/) article that shows how to run a stored procedure when the server instance starts, but I can't seem to find something similar for the database itself coming online.

I need to run a stored procedure when a database comes online, for example, if a database is restored under a new name or on a separate server/instance from where it was backed up.  I figured I could technically run a job that periodically checks for any new databases but the database might be restored onto a server which doesn't have this job installed so that's a bit of a dead end.

Another example is when the server is restarted, or if the database was taken offline for any reason and then put back online.  Essentially, any time the database comes online I'd like to know about it via a stored procedure being fired.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need it to run as part of a restore then it should be part of your restore script.

Comment: @Larnu In an ideal world I'd agree, but we don't have any control over the customers environments.

Comment: If you have no control over them, how do you propose you control the behaviour of the server **after** they've restored the database? If this is part of an installation process, then it needs to be part of the script that restores the database (so you should be provided a restoration script for them). Then, if the customer doesn't use those scripts, which us **documented** as part of the "install process",  then they didn't complete the process correctly, and you can't be responsible for any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Sure sure, but as I said, it was only 1 example, any time the database comes online we'd like to fire a stored proc, like when the server restarts.

Comment: Then you would also need to add instructions to add a job to the agent that runs that task at the instance starting.

Comment: Yes, but if they restore a database to a new instance that we don't know about, we wouldn't be able to create the start up task.  I really do appreciate your input but the only thing I want to know is whether or not it's possible to fire a stored proc when the database comes online.

Comment: From the perspective of the way you are talking (which is that you want the database to do it), the answer is no. A database doesn't do anything in terms of SQL Server; it holds the information for your data and object, but it doesn't actually "run" anything. All the processing, such as automated tasks, it managed by the server; most likely Agent. The database isn't "self aware" and realises that it's "come online" and therefore runs a process on itself. Personally, I would actually see that as a security risk; can you imagine a database emailing all it's info every time it "came online"?

Comment: This has all the telltale signs of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I went through every possible way of doing this, I looked at `Server Triggers`:
You can do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TrackDBStarted] 
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE, ALTER_DATABASE
```

which will give you when a database is CREATED but not when it's RESTORED / ATTACHED so that's not going to work.

You can use `Extended Events` as it HAS an event for `database_started`:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TrackDBStarted] 
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.database_started
( ACTION ( sqlserver.database_name ) )
```

but unfortunately you can't `Target` `T-SQL` so that's not going to work.

One guaranteed way to do it, is to create a `Startup Procedure` that'll allow you to create a global `Temp Table` which won't go out of scope for the duration of the server's uptime.  From that `Stored Procedure` you can ensure there's an `Agent Job` created that'll check the list of databases every x time delta and perform actions on the newly `Onlined` Databases.  It's a lengthy piece of code but it CREATES/QUERIES/DELETES the actions performed so anyone can hopefully glean ideas from it.  I've tried to comment where necessary but if you don't understand some of the items, I'd recommend first reading up about them.

If anyone has a better way of doing this, I'd be happy to learn.

**CREATION**

```
USE MASTER;
GO

IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'dbo.STARTUPPROC' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[STARTUPPROC];
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'dbo.CHECKDBS' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECKDBS];
GO

/* Create the stored procedure that will check for any new databases. */
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECKDBS]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Database   sysname;

    DECLARE c_databases CURSOR LOCAL FOR    SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
                                            WHERE name NOT IN ( N'master', N'model', N'msdb', N'tempdb' )
                                            AND name NOT IN ( SELECT [Database] FROM ##DBList )
                                            AND state = 0;  -- Online

    OPEN c_databases;
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_databases INTO @Database;

    WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
    BEGIN
        IF ( HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME( @Database, 'DATABASE', 'ANY' ) = 1 )  
        BEGIN

            /**************************************
            *** Do database related tasks here. ***
            ***************************************/

            INSERT INTO ##DBList ( [Database] )
            VALUES ( @Database );
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_databases INTO @Database;
    END

    CLOSE c_databases;
    DEALLOCATE c_databases;
GO

/* 
Create the stored procedure that will:
1. Create the temporary table so it doesn't go out of scope. 
2. Create the job that will periodically call the CHECKDBS stored procedure.
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STARTUPPROC]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Create the temporary table if it doesn't already exist.
    IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'tempdb..##DBList' ) IS Null )
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE ##DBList
        (
            [Database]  sysname NOT NULL,                       -- Name of the database.
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [Database] ASC
            )
        );
    END

    DECLARE @JobName    sysname         = N'DBCheck';       -- Name of the job.
    DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(30)    = @@SERVERNAME;     -- SQL Server on which this job will be configured.
    DECLARE @JobDate    nvarchar(8)     = CONVERT( nvarchar(8), SYSDATETIME(), 112 );   -- Job start date.
    DECLARE @Command    nvarchar(max)   = N'EXEC [dbo].[CHECKDBS]';                     -- The T-SQL command to run in the step.

    -- Check if the job exists and create it if it doesn't.
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = @JobName )
    BEGIN
        -- Add the job.
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job 
            @job_name = @JobName;

        -- Add the job step.
        -- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
            @job_name = @JobName,
            @step_name = N'Job Step',
            @subsystem = N'TSQL',
            @command = @Command;

        -- Schedule the job.
        -- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobschedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name = @JobName,
            @name = N'Minute',                  -- Name of the job schedule.
            @enabled = 1,                       -- Will be enabled.
            @freq_type = 4,                     -- Daily.
            @freq_interval = 1,                 -- Every x days.
            @freq_subday_type = 4,              -- Minutes.
            @freq_subday_interval = 1,          -- Sub day interval.
            @freq_relative_interval = 0,        -- Only used when @freq_type = 32 so set to 0.
            @freq_recurrence_factor = 0,        -- Not used for @freq_type = 4 so set to 0.
            @active_start_date = @JobDate,      -- Date on which job execution should commence, must be greater than or equal to 19900101.
            @active_end_date = 99991231,        -- No end date.
            @active_start_time = 0,             -- Start job at 00:00:00.
            @active_end_time = 235959;          -- End job at 23:59:59.

        -- Add the job to the SQL Server.
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
            @job_name = @JobName,
            @server_name = @ServerName;
    END
GO

/* Mark the stored proc for startup. */
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'dbo.STARTUPPROC' ) IS NOT Null )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM MASTER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = N'STARTUPPROC' AND OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID( ROUTINE_NAME ), 'ExecIsStartup' ) = 1 )
    EXEC SP_PROCOPTION N'STARTUPPROC', 'STARTUP', 'ON';
GO
```

**QUERY**

```
USE MASTER;
GO
SELECT * FROM SYS.CONFIGURATIONS WHERE NAME = N'scan for startup procs';
SELECT * FROM MASTER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = N'STARTUPPROC' AND OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID( ROUTINE_NAME ), 'ExecIsStartup' ) = 1;
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DBCheck';
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name IN ( N'STARTUPPROC', N'CHECKDBS' );
SELECT * from tempdb.sys.objects WHERE name = N'##DBList';
GO
```

**REMOVAL**

```
USE MASTER;
GO

-- Delete the job.
IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N'DBCheck' )
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = N'DBCheck';
GO

-- Remove the stored procedure and turn off the auto-startup.
IF EXISTS ( SELECT Null FROM MASTER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = N'STARTUPPROC' AND OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID( ROUTINE_NAME ), 'ExecIsStartup' ) = 1 )
    EXEC SP_PROCOPTION N'STARTUPPROC', 'STARTUP', 'OFF';
GO

-- Drop the stored procedures.
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'dbo.STARTUPPROC' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[STARTUPPROC];
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'dbo.CHECKDBS' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[CHECKDBS];
GO

-- Drop the temporary table.
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'tempdb..##DBList' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP TABLE ##DBList;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your requirement, you are looking for execution of procedure when SQL Server instance comes online. For that you can go through below article.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1574/automatically-running-stored-procedures-at-sql-server-startup/

Comment: thanks for this, I have this already, I'm looking to execute a stored procedure when a database comes online, this would happen when the server restarts, when the db was taken offline or when the database gets restored.